# Visual Studio Code replaces my opened tabs when opening file from Finder

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using **Visual Studio Code v1.21.1** on **macOS Sierra**.

I have a *workspace* with about 9 or 10 tabs with the files that I used all the time. But if I want to open a new file associated with VSC by double clicking it on Finder, instead of just opening it in my current instance as a new tab, it closes the instance (with all the other 10 files) and opens alone.

I can't find any setting that changes this behavior to what other editors do, and which is basically opening a file from the operating system's Finder in a new tab, whilst keeping all my other stuff opened.

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior on v1.22 and W10.  Even if the new file is from a different workspace.  You don't have   "window.openFilesInNewWindow": "off",
set to "on" by any chance?

Comment: Thanks. In my computer that setting is set to off. But also I've noted that if I try to change it (by clicking on the pencil icon next to it) it opens the contextual menu with options "on", "off" and "default" but then it is not possible to select any of these. Just as in my system that would be a read-only setting. Isn't it weird?

Comment: I just updated it to v1.22.1 and this does not happen anymore (although window.openFilesInNewWindow continues to be a read-only-like setting).

Comment: you should disable preview mode under `workbench.editor.enablePreview` to solve this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This happens because of preview mode in VsCode which opens the file as a preview (the file opened as a preview will have italic file name), you have to pin the preview by editing or douple clicking the tab.

you can also disable the preview mode from the setting screen under 
`workbench.editor.enablePreview`

you can find detailed explanation here https://www.brcline.com/blog/force-vscode-open-files-new-tab